# Problem with executing shell script from Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Makefile:

```
$(shell ./test.sh)
```

---

1st experiment: test.sh

```
echo "hi"
```

Error I get:

```
Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

---

2nd experiment:
test.sh

```
echo("hi")
```

Errors I get:

```
./test.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `"hi"' 
./test.sh: line 1: `echo("hi")'
```

Doesn't make any sense...it looks as if 'Make' tries to impose its syntax on the shell script, but the shell script wants its own too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try `./test.sh`.

In the first experiment, the result is

```
hi
```

When you run `make`, the line `$(shell ./test.sh)` evaluates as `hi`, which Make doesn't know how to interpret.

In the second experiment,

```
./test.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `"hi"'
./test.sh: line 1: `echo("hi")'
```

You've written a shell script that doesn't have correct shell syntax, so it fails. It fails whether you run it or Make runs it.

Comment: I tried that, but it says: "Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop." aswell. I don't know what to make of this..

Comment: Oh damn, apparently I can't just put that line anywhere, it has to be a recipe. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not exactly, you can use $(warning $(shell ... )), warning is guaranteed to produce null output, then you can use (fake) assignment AAA := $(shell ...) - that all depends on your particular needs.

Comment: @pmod: true, and you can also use `$(info $(shell ...))`, like `warning` but less urgent.

Comment: @Blub Makefile:1: *** missing separator usually means you have spaces instead of tabs.  Makefile only likes tabs

Comment: I have a shell script which uses echo -n to list the names of files processed. Make is trying to interpret these as commands :-) How do I signal from the script to make that it should ignore the script's stdout?

Comment: @PeterFlynn: I can't see it from that description. If you can prepare a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it might make a good question.

Comment: False alarm. I had left a $(shell ...) around the command without assigning its output to anything. More coffee needed.